# How to save Excel document created from Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I feel dumb asking this, but right now I'm using Apache POI to write to an Excel document.  But as of right now, every time I run the program it doesn't save the data to the excel document, meaning the next time I run it the data from previous trails isn't there.  Is there a line of code for saving all the info gathered during a trial so that it is still there in future trials?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt very clear, I guess what I mean is when I run the program and gather information from the user. I want it to permanently save the data to the excel document.  As of now it will create the excel document but once I run the program again, the data from the previous run is no longer stored.  I want to be able to keep the data from each successive run.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to save the created workbook to the file system, I think you want [Workbook.write](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) and one of the constructors for the spreadsheet format you use to read it in again (e.g. XSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream from [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html))

> **write**
>      void write(java.io.OutputStream stream) java.io.IOException
>     Write out this workbook to an Outputstream.
>     **Parameters:**
>    stream - - the java OutputStream you> wish to write to
>     **Throws:**
>     java.io.IOException - if anything can't> be written.

Answer (score 1):

As Paul mentioned, you need `workbook.write()` ,

here's usage:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
.......
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\file.xls"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on the JED website you might want to check out which demonstrates how to collect data from an HTML table and save it to an Excel file using the POI library.  You should get all you need in the way of servlet code to replicate for your purposes.

Try: http://jed-datatables.ca/jed/examples/exporttoexcel2.html

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you should end your code with:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelFilePath);
wb.write(outputStream);
outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
```